# Find the value of f(S)?

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $z = x + iy$ be a complex number, where $x$ and $y \in\mathbb R$, and let
$f(z) = u(x, y) + iv(x, y)$, where $u$ and $v$ are real valued, be an analytic function on $\mathbb C$.Find the image of the set
$$S = \{z : x > 0, 0 < y < 2\}$$
under the transformation $f(z) = iz + 1$.

I was trying this question many times , but I didn't get it . I was using the bilinear transformation formula but i didn't get the values.

Comment: First, everything before the words "Find the image ..." does not seem to have anything to do with the the question. Second, you don't need to use formulas. Instead, **draw a sketch** of the region $S$ in the complex plane and think about where each point in that region goes under the transformation $z\mapsto iz+1$.

Comment: im very weak in complex anlaysis...so pliz explain me in detail @ henning makholm

Comment: This is not complex _analysis_, it is just complex _numbers_.

Comment: @henning pliz explain i don't know

Answer (score 3):

Draw the set $S$.

If you multiply a complex number by $i$, you are rotating it $90^\circ$ CCW around the origin. If you add $1$ to a complex number, you translate it $1$ unit rightwards.

Now make these transformations to the set $S$. What do you get?

Comment: sir pliz  explain me in detail   , i have multiply by i , and  i get -z+i  after  that what i have do@ ajotatxe

Comment: No. Take $z \in S$ and multiply with i ......

Comment: pliz expalin me in detail,,,,,,i don't know @ fred